# Helm install stable/efs-provisioner - Do they need to be installed in same namespace as the pods/containers that will mount the volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-efs

I have an app that I package and deploy using helm. I need to mount volume to my container with persistent volume back by EFS storage. I am trying to install efs-provisioner using helm stable/efs-provisioner charts. I am wondering if they need to be installed with the same namespace as my project helm charts or can this efs-provisioner be in a different namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it in any namespace. It will create a StorageClass which is not namespace scoped.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/